# How can I display monthly Calendar view in Android as required?

Tags: android, api, user-interface, calendar, android-calendar

My academic project require displaying the current month's calendar with few details like number of visits a user has made on particular day. No other functionality is required like reminder, note, etc. I just need to display the following format. I searched many calendar APIs but unable to find one which serves the purpose. Your help would be highly appreciated.

[image: Here is the design I need to implement in app]

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own calendar with use of a View pager and GridView . As i can see you need to select multiple days in particular month, you need a a customized one .
Checkout these links with, you'll get an idea about it:

1.[Caldroid](https://github.com/roomorama/Caldroid)

2.[calendarview](https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview)

These are some awesome work by the coders you can use this in your project and take the idea of building a calender on your own.Thx.